# Add several Vectors to a Vector of Vectors doesn't work, Java

Tags: java, vector

I want to put some Vectors in a Vector of Vectors. I do this in a loop and in the end there is only the last added vector in it but as often as the count of the vectors I want to add.

```
public void initVectors() {

    rows = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
    Vector<String> data = new Vector<String>();

    Vector<String> t = new Vector<String>();
    String aLine;
    try {
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("module.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fin));
        // extract data
        while ((aLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(aLine, ",");
            t.clear();
            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                t.addElement(st.nextToken());
                // System.out.println(st.nextToken());
            }

            System.out.println(t);
            System.out.println("add it");
            rows.addElement(t);

        }

        Enumeration vEnum = rows.elements();
        System.out.println("Elements in vector:");
        while (vEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
            System.out.print(vEnum.nextElement());
            System.out.println();
        }


        br.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

My output is:
[GDI 1, 4, 1.0]
add it
[Physik, 6, 1.3]
add it
Elements in vector:
[Physik, 6, 1.3]
[Physik, 6, 1.3]

Comment: `t` is still the same reference when you add it again to `rows`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what can I do?

Comment: Side note: use ArrayList instead of Vector (`Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList())` if thread safety is a requirement), and use Iterator instead of Enumeration.

Comment: The row vector is my dataVector for a JTable. I use DefaultTableModel and the setDataVector. Will it work with ArrayList too?

Answer (score 3):

The `Vector` `row` keeps just a reference to `t`, it does not copy its elements. When you change `t` outside you are affecting the contents of `row`.

Instead of using `t.clear()` use `t = new Vector()` to create a new object and not affect what has been added to `rows`.